# create generic list object from datatable which has different schema at runtime

Tags: list, generics, dynamic, datatable

Datatable should be converted to a generic list. The datatable may have different schema at runtime.so extracting the class type for the generic list becomes difficult. Because as the columns differ at run time, I could'nt create property for the class type accordingly. I want to know how to do that. i am using c#.

Comment: What have you tried? What is going wrong, specifically?  (And what programming language would you like??)

Comment: I have a datatable. Which should be converted to a generic list. The datatable may have different schema at runtime.so extracting the class type for the generic list becomes difficult. Because as the columns differ at run time, I could'nt create property for the class type accordingly. I want to know how to do that.  i using c#.